# How many 9-digit values are there with listed conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

How many 9-digit numbers are there ​​which are all different digits, ending with 2 and when its divided with 3 his remainder is 1?

Comment: Hey man, please don't just expect us to do your homework for you. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please show some effort.

Comment: sorry but it isnt for my homework, its sample of exam and i really cant answer it

Comment: @Ivan: Regardless, you should still offer at least some considerations or say that you cannot find out where to start and ask for hints then.

Comment: Side note:  you should probably clarify what you mean by a $9$-digit value.  I assume you mean that it has to be at least $10^8$ but perhaps you mean something else.

Comment: 9-digit numbers, so how many 9-digit numbers are there with this conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

- A numbers remainder modulo $3$ is equal to the remainder of that numbers digit sum modulo $3$.
- $0+1+2+...+9=45$ has remainder zero modulo $3$.
- Remove any number of the form $3k+2$ from above for the rest to have remainder $1$ modulo $3$.
- Once you have found a set of digits that will work, the digit $2$ has a fixed place and the remaining $8$ digits can be shuffled around producing different solutions.

Comment: so if we fix 2 on end, then we have smallest number 134567892, and this number is evenly divisible by 3, so the correct answer will be 8! ?

Comment: @Ivan: You are right that once you have found a set of digits that works, then that produces $8!$ different numbers that will work. But $193456782$ is divisible by $3$ and you stated that it should have remainder $1$ modulo $3$. So what are you really after?